# 'Code zoom' feature to view code in expanded popup

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, user-interface, user-experience

Right now, viewing code on Stack Overflow is quite inconvenient as it's displayed in a small text box where lines don't wrap.

I hope a "code zoom" feature can be added - similar to the one available in Discourse forums.

It makes a huge difference - and really I think we deserve to view code in a more human-oriented way by now in 2023.

Here's an example from Late Night Software forums (hover mouse over the code block to see the 'code zoom' icon in the upper right corner):

https://forum.latenightsw.com/t/myriad-tables-questions/389/180?u=leo_r

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how, and I don't have time to try right now, but it is very likely possible to write a Tampermonkey userscript that would add that feature. If you do build a userscript that does that, consider posting it over on [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) (a SE site dedicated to user-created userscripts and apps)

Comment: I would not call anything Discourse does (sorry Jeff) an example for Stack Overflow. I mean it's 2023, and each and every Discourse site still blinks three times in my browser before showing the content I want to see, _after_ downloading about 6 MB of JavaScript, taking over 500ms to render a page.

Comment: Your comment confuses me, @CodeCaster.  In what year was that behavior ever acceptable? Or were you just reminding us all that it is 2023? I guess that's helpful; sometimes, in the first few months of the new year, I forget what year it is and say/write the wrong one.

Comment: @Cody heh. I just wanted to mention that, so people could calculate that they've had 9 (is it 9 already?) years to fix the reading experience.

Comment: *"... is quite inconvenient as it's displayed in a small text box where lines don't wrap"* Line-wrapped code? is that even a thing?

Comment: @KevinB *"...Line-wrapped code? is that even a thing?"* unless i misunderstand what you mean, yes - it's a standard behavior of any code editor (or text editor for that matter)

Comment: I never turn line-wrap on (menu *Document* → *"Line Wrapping"* in [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)). It is even more confusing. Especially if there is indentation involved, but not only then.

Answer (score 1):

How would this make "a huge difference"? As you can see here, that example code snippet would be perfectly readable if posted on Stack Overflow now, save for two extremely long lines, the contents of which aren't really even important to understanding what the code does:

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use scripting additions

use script "Myriad Tables Lib" version "1.0.13"
set tableData to {}
set theNames to {"Harry", "Warren", "Glenn", "Zak", "Clint", "Clark", "Harry", "Warren", "Glenn", "Zak", "Clint", "Clark"}

repeat 5 times
    set thisRow to {}
    repeat 8 times
        set the end of thisRow to some item of theNames
    end repeat
    set the end of tableData to thisRow
end repeat

set columnHeadings to {"1-left, left", "2-right,right", "3-center, center", "4-natural, natural", "5-left,right", "6-right,Left", "7-right,center", "8-center,right"}
set columnWidth to 125
set newTable to ¬
    make new table with data tableData ¬
        column headings columnHeadings

modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {1} ¬
    head alignment align left ¬
    entry alignment align left ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {2} ¬
    head alignment align right ¬
    entry alignment align right ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {3} ¬
    head alignment align center ¬
    entry alignment align center ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {4} ¬
    head alignment align natural ¬
    entry alignment align natural ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {5} ¬
    head alignment align left ¬
    entry alignment align right ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {6} ¬
    head alignment align right ¬
    entry alignment align left ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {7} ¬
    head alignment align right ¬
    entry alignment align center ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
modify columns in table newTable ¬
    columns list {8} ¬
    head alignment align center ¬
    entry alignment align right ¬
    column width columnWidth ¬
    
set tableResult to display table newTable
```

Besides being of dubious utility, this type of "zoom" has a ***severe* disadvantage**: it makes it impossible to read the code in context with the surrounding explanation.

This seems like it would be somewhere between "useless" and "a severe hindrance". Just write the code using sane line lengths. I can *easily* fit 80 characters on a line in Stack Overflow's code blocks without the need for any vertical scrolling:

```
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Personally, when I write code in the "real world", I limit line lengths to 100 characters (rather than the traditional 80 characters), but for *expository* code snippets (as should be posted here), even 80 characters seems more than sufficient.

Comment: FYI, I need to scroll to see your the end of your line full of Ms (because I'm using a 175% zoom level on SO by default). Although, funnily enough, with both 150% and 200% zoom level, I don't need to scroll (150% because it's small enough, and with 200% the side panel with HNQ & co disappears, which leaves more space for questions & answers).

Comment: @Dada For what it's worth, Stack Overflow (and the entire Stack Exchange network) does not officially support such zoom levels. In fact, [no zooming is supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008); the site is designed to be viewed only with a 100% zoom. At other zoom levels, many things are subject to breaking.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. It's pretty exhausting for me to read SO without zooming, and I'd be surprised if I was the only one, so I find it surprising that SO doesn't support zooming...

Comment: The argument of the "***severe disadvantage***" is a bit flawed IMO, you only (need to) read the "*surrounding explanation*" once, maybe twice... And if that explanation is continuously needed to understand/follow the Code, maybe it should be placed as Comment(s) ***in*** the Code... Or the User could always open 2 Tabs on the same Page, or even 2 Browser Instances, one for the "standard view" with Question + Answer(s) + Code Block(s), and one for the specific Code Block in Popup or Full Screen...

Comment: @CodyGray It's unfortunate that the site does not support some pretty basic accessibility. And I'll point out that on my 4K monitor, with my browser occupying one corner (effectively 1080p and full-screen), I have a horizontal scroll bar. And I don't zoom.

Comment: the code example you posted is very hard to read here. even considering that the code was especially carefully formatted to consist of mostly unusually short lines. the claim "two extremely long lines, the contents of which aren't really even important" is especially strange, as naturally you first need to horizontally scroll back and forth to understand if it's "important". plus most code examples contain quite a few long lines that are long enough to enable horizontal scroll.

Comment: the proposed "code zoom" feature is an OPTION for those who want to actually see and understand code samples in a humanly-readable, convenient way. i find it totally PATHETIC that it's exactly us, developers, who have to struggle in the year 2023 with this kind of archaic, inconvenient, and user-unfriendly way of displaying the code.

Comment: I infer from that comment that you think I am not a human, not a developer, and not even a user. In fact, none of those are true. Really, what you have is an opinion, and I have a different one. There's nothing PATHETIC about that.

Comment: @CodyGray: like i mentioned, i propose an OPTION that would preserve your preferred way of viewing code - while giving other users an OPTION to view code in a more convenient way for them. i don't understand why this OPTION that doesn't change anything for you - but improves experience for others - would evoke such strong opposition from you. the pathetic thing is that we don't have this OPTION in 2023.